# sqlite does not see new tables I added to the db

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have a database that has 7 tables and am calling them from my app simply using sqlite queries ...
am not new to this I made to apps work greatly even with encryption ..

am building now a new app and decide to add  2 new tables my db ,
but when I call them sqlites doesnot see them and return me with an error "No such table :history"
I have added these new tables simply using sqlitemanger add-on that comes with firefox as I always do.

In the terminal I can see them and I can get data from them , but that is not the case in my app..

do you have any idea?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete your app from simulator and run it again.I think your updated database is not copied.

Comment: thnx :) i shoud delelte the database from application support directory ... clean the build and run